# PhpStorm wrap qutes to backslash

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

In PhpStoem 10 really unusable feature.
I copy, for exaple

```
'.$this->createUrl('edit', array('id' => $model->id).'
```

and paste to my view:

```
echo '<a href="PASTE HERE">Edit</a>';
```

and got:

```
echo '<a href="\'.$this->createUrl(\'edit\', array(\'id\' => $data->id)).\'">Edit</a>';
```

OK, 
I copy in my view:

```
echo '<a href="'.$this->createUrl('edit', array('id' => $model->id).'">edit</a>';
```

and past bottom line. Voila - same result:

```
echo '<a href="\'.$this->createUrl(\'edit\', array(\'id\' => $data->id)).\'">Edit</a>';
```

How to disable that feature?

Comment: Use `Paste Simple` instead of ordinary `Paste`. **P.S.** You may assign another (simpler) shortcut for that action in `Settings/Preferences | Keymap`.. or even swap them around.

Answer (score 1):

This feature was introduced as a result of fixing [WI-309](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-309). Unfortunately there is currently no way to turn it off. If you miss this possibility, please, vote for [WI-29782](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-29782).
the only possible workaround is using `Edit/Paste Simple` instead of `Paste`. You can re-map shortcuts in `Settings/Keymap` to make `Paste Simple` available on `Ctrl+V`

Answer (score 0):

This issue is finally fixed as of PhpStorm version 2020.2. There is a checkbox in Preferences > General > Smart Keys > PHP > "Escape symbols on paste in string literals". Uncheck the box to disable this annoying feature.

See: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-31941